# Group by and percentage as column for multiple variables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by, pivot-table, window-functions

I have a Trip table where each trip has a destination ID, trip takers ethnicity (black/white/Asian) and trip mode (bike, car etc.)

I am trying to group by and summarize for Destination and other variables (ethnicity and mode) in Postgres. The desired output would have one row for each destination with %White/Black or %Bike trips as column.

I was able to do it partially for destination and ethnicity using the following code

I used this window function

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT destination, ethnicity, count(activity_id) as total_dest_trips
   FROM   test
   GROUP  BY destination, ethnicity
   )
SELECT destination, ethnicity, total_dest_trips*100/sum(total_dest_trips) OVER (PARTITION BY destination_trct) AS share
FROM   x ORDER BY destination;
```

I understand I can use the code for each variable (ethnicity/mode) and use the crosstab() function. But is there any way where I can do this simultaneously in one step for all variables?

Comment: how will you combine rows of (destination & ethnicity) to rows of (destination & trip_mode) ? what should the output look like? :: There are big gaps in your question i.e. include some `sample data` and provide the `expected result` (& do not use images of these tings). Consider using the Help link in this site's footer for how to ask questions